# Input Tkinter, .get(), all data in dictionary, insert utf-8 value in xml

Tags: python, xml, tkinter, utf-8, overwrite

i'm new to stackoverflow and to programming in python. I want to develop a program that takes some data from Tkinter build interface and when data is send is inputed in xml file on direct tag that i decide.

When printing directly in console, everything stays ok, except if the output is in dictionary. But even if I try with only one variable, and output in console in still ok, when I insert text in xml I loose my char "čžš...". It also breaks all other char in xml that where previously there.

For now my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

def main():
    window = Tk()
    name_l = Label(window, text=" Ime: ")
    name_l.grid(row=2, column=0)
    name = Entry(window)
    name.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # seznam uspehov na spričevalu
    uspeh_list = ["izberi", "odličen"]

    selected_uspeh = StringVar()
    selected_uspeh.set(uspeh_list[0])

    uspeh = Label(window, text=" Uspeh: ")
    uspeh.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)
    uspeh_menu = OptionMenu(window, selected_uspeh, *uspeh_list)
    uspeh_menu.grid(row=5, column=1)

    def get_data():

        name_dijak = name.get()
        uspeh_dijak = selected_uspeh.get()
        podatki_o_spricevalu = {"name": name_dijak, "uspeh":uspeh_dijak}

        print podatki_o_spricevalu
        return podatki_o_spricevalu


    def make_xml():

        podatki = get_data()
        print ("Tole so podatki v obliki dictionary:")
        print podatki
        # odpremo pravo xml datoteko
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

        with open('primer.xml','r') as tree_file:
            tree = ET.parse(tree_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        name = root[0][1].text
        root[0][1].text = podatki["name"]

        uspeh = root[0][4].text
        root[0][4].text = podatki["uspeh"]
        tree.write('primer_out.xml')

        print root[0][1].text




    # gumb naredi xml
    Label(window, text="Make xml:", ).grid(row=20, column=0, sticky=E)
    Button(window, text="XML ", width=14, command=make_xml).grid(
        row=20, column=1, sticky=E)


    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to do few things myself: 
 1. I tried using another computer where system is windows with our language, that failed.

2. I opened vprasaj.py in notepad and save it as unicode, as utf-8 and as ASCII, that failed.
3. I tried to loose the dictionary and try it just with one variable. All commands print in the console work fine, but not when inserted in xml
4. In dictionary i tried writing u"some text", i saw it somewhere but not sure what it means :S
5. I tried number of things that i didn't fully understand.

So, what I need is maybe some guidance, how to change my code or. some example, on how to take simple text from user and insert it in prewritten xml file, so to not loose any of my "čšž..."

Thank you, for the time, even if just reading. As I said I'm new in programming and I probably won't be able to follow very complex solutions. I will absolutely try. And this is badly written code, but I will polish it along the way.

Comment: Please try to reduce that code down to an [mcve]. You've posted way too much code.

Comment: I edit my code. Left entry field and drop down list. Is it still to much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. To transfer name with "čžš" and other fields I just needed to write in the output file what the encoding is:

```
tree.write('primer_out.xml', encoding="UTF-8")
```

It added all the letters in .xml file, and that is all I need.

Thank you for your help.